# @PostConstruct calls service that autowires the caller class

Tags: spring

I have two classes:

```
@Component
public class Cache {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userService.doSth();
    }
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private Cache cache;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void doSth() {
        repository.doSth();
    }
}
```

If i want to deploy my application, i get this exception:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cache': Invocation of init method failed

And all the autowired fields are null in the UserServiceImpl.

If i delete the @Autowired private Cache cache part from my service then it works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Just wanted to find out if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the definition of PostConstruct.

> The PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be
>   executed after dependency injection is done to perform any
>   initialization. This method MUST be invoked before the class is put
>   into service

.

In you flow, i believe you are waiting for the cache to be autowired with userService and your user service is waiting for cache to be autowired. I guess this is kind of creating dependency issue. You might have to rearrange your logic to avoid this dependency. Since i don't know about your complete flow, i may not be able to suggest a code alternative, but this should give you a gist why its happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I rearranged the logic and it helped. in the future i will try to avoid this situation :)